# Select arithmetic operation e.g. 2 + 2 eval and echo result in the minibuffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode, calc, org-table

I have an org file with lots of tables containing simple arithmetic values like "2 + 2", "1 + 2 + 3", "3 * 4"(notice - no elisp here) that I want to keep as is, without transforming into corresponding arithmetic results(for transparency/visibility reasons).

But I would like to find a way to quickly select any cell/arithmetic operation and get its result(ideally in popup/separate minibuffer).

Is it possible?

Basically it's a combination of `(calculator)` but in non-iterative way using the selected region.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to a function that does exactly that

`(calc-grab-region)`

> Parse the region as a vector of numbers and push it on the Calculator stack.